# How to match a button push in a table of buttons to specific data on the server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If you believe the title can be edited please feel free to do so.

I have small web app that's used to search for entries in a database. You are given a table of entries, and you can click on one of those entries to expand it down (accordion) to view more details.

I want to add a few buttons to manipulate the entries in different ways, however, I am not sure how to pass information from the button click to a javascript function that I can use to identify and change the data in the database. Pretty much there may be 50 rows in the table, but I want to identify which one the button was pushed in (specifically something that can be used to uniquely identify the row in the database, not in the HTML table).

How/what should I pass to a function when the button is clicked?

I apologize if this is too broad, I have absolutely no idea where to start, any guidance is welcome.

Comment: Your event handler has a reference to the element that caused the event to fire.  You are probably looking for e.target.  As for which row, when rendering the buttons, you can do something like data-id='<insert the id here>'

Comment: When you populate your table with the data, do you give the rows an id matching the id of the entry in the database? That's how it usually is done. You just need to find the event.target's id and pass it.

Comment: What are you using to generate your html tables?

Comment: Ah! That makes sense, just throw a unique ID into that row. Can the button, which is a child element, access that data-id of the parent element? . Scottie, I am using JQuery templates.

Answer (score 0):

Everything depends on how you submit button click to the server. If you do this with ajax call then the simplest solution will be to add entry id to the request. You can add this id to the table row with data-entry-id="{id_from_table}" and then retrieve it in js. If your buttons are simple links then you can change it to button/input with type submit and wrap it with form which would have hidden field of entry_id.